# Circuit to regulate output voltage to a reversible DC motor for a test rig

Tags: power-supply

I am creating a test rig to test the capability of an autopilot computer. This AP computer outputs 4-12 VDC to a reversible DC brushed motor. The test set I am making uses this DC motor on a swivel to rotate a heading sensor. Trouble is at 12 VDC the motor spins the heading sensor too quickly and changing my spur and pinion gear to reduce this rate of turn is not an option. I have noticed at 2.5-3 VDC the motor spins at the perfect rate of turn. The AP computer switches polarity output to the motor to change direction of the craft it is controlling. I had thought about a step down, but it does not work when polarity is reversed from the output on the computer.

At this point I think I either need two step downs using a diode to create a reverse polarity circuit, or I need to somehow use diodes in series to create my own step down using diodes on both the positive and ground wires. So that any output by the computer (usually matches input voltage at 12 VDC) can be reduced to approx 2.5 VDC. Perhaps there is an easier way to accomplish this. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Motor is activated between the ranges of 1-15 VDC and with the weight of the rig it is rotating consumes a max peak amp draw of 8 amps and an operating/nominal amp draw of 4 amps.

Power supply for the rig is a 12 VDC 18 Ah battery powering the AP computer which can output up to input voltage at 30 amps peak and up to 20 amps continuous.

Comment: If your motor drive circuit can tolerate it, and the signal is not already PWM, you can chop the signal, to lower its **effective** voltage. If that interests you, I could give a more extended answer.

Comment: replace the motor with one designed for a higher voltage.

Comment: I appreciate the responses. I want to clarify that we can't change this motor. There are too many parameters involved in doing so and I will run out of backing to support this project if I were to attempt at doing so. There is also no way to regulate or manipulate the power out circuit on these computers. This is a test rig for the computers themselves and we need to be able to swap out 40-50 of them a day so modifying them is out of the question. Instead we need to regulate the power output and also make this voltage regulator work seamlessly when  polarity is reversed.